# Why was Civil War billed as a Captain America movie as opposed to an Avengers movie?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, marketing

So with the other individual movies (Thor, Iron Man, The first two Cap' films), individual Avengers may play cameos or supporting roles. In the Avengers films, it has been a collaborative effort with no individual getting a significantly larger amount of screen time than the others.

In Civil War, Tony Stark gets at least as much screen time as Steve Rogers, and some of the others (Natasha Romanoff, Vision, Wanda Maximoff) come pretty close to getting a "co-star" level of screen time as opposed to "supporting cast".

Given all of that, what executive and marketing decisions lead to Civil War being billed a Captain America movie?

Comment: Related SFF question: [Why is Civil War a “Captain America” movie?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/127549/21267)

Comment: On a somewhat meta point, I think they reserve the 'Avengers' title for movies that involves potential destruction of the entire world/solar system/galaxy/universe, that also have a large cast. GotG had the peril, but not the cast, CW had the cast, but not the peril.

Comment: @SGR That is a reasonable viewpoint that might even be worth being fleshed out into an answer of its own.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are certainly right that this film seems to be chock full of Avengers. However, it is still a **rather personal Captain America movie** through and through. You could as well ask that question about Natasha Romanoff, the Black Widow, in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*. It's about more than just screen time.

While there is a larger conflict between the two parties in the Avengers arising due to the UN act on limiting their individuality, the thing that makes it escalate is actually **Steve's friendship to Bucky, the Winter Soldier**, and his tries to help him and handle the matter personally, against his fellow Avengers and the new established laws. **Captain America is the primary driver behind the opposition** in that film and he only is **because of his personal matters**. While Captain America refused to sign the UN law, he was still smart enough to not go downright postal against the law enforcement and his Avengers colleagues, not until he has a personal reason for doing so. If it weren't for his friend Bucky, he'd just sit around abiding the new UN law, even if under protest.

This is still a rather **personal Steve-story** embedded into the admittedly larger conflict about responsibility that touches all the MCU heroes. Even Tony, who turns out to be quite personally involved in the matter himself is not so much until the very end.

While marginally referencing the larger events at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and employing characters introduced therein, the movie is primarily a **direct (and thematic) continuation of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier***, concentrating on the eponymous character introduced in that, and his friendship to Steve Rogers introduced in *Captain America: The First Avenger*, together with a variety of other minor characters only known from the previous movie, like Sharon Carter or Brock Rumlow (Crossbones).

Comment: Why wasn't Age of Ultron an Iron Man movie?

Comment: Geez, why aren't they all Iron Man movies then?

Comment: Completely agree with the analysis, that's the example to good multiple answered question +1

Comment: _"If it weren't for his friend Bucky, he'd just sit still abiding the new UN law."_ Really?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, probably.

Comment: @KutuluMike Are you two sure? Napoleon, before Bucky was involved in the scandal at the UN, Steve was clearly opposed to the treaty. **But**, KutuluMike, he didn't "refuse to sign" until _after_ he knew Bucky was framed. So the actual timeline of events was that Steve was clearly against it but undecided until the UN blast which put Bucky in the crosshair. He didn't make his decision until Bucky was captured and Tony failed to persuade Steve to sign- Steve handed back the pen which explicitly symbolized that his decision was _now_ finally made. So you both didn't "watch the movie" haha.

Comment: There is a difference, though, between being opposed to the law and merely refusing to sign it and **going on a downright rampage fighting against the enforcement**. No matter if he agrees with the law or not, he's not stupid enough to directly *fight* against it in those difficult times, at least not unless it's about his best friend.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm not trying to argue the "difference", so I don't know why you're trying to get us off course. I'm talking about your line that, "If it weren't for his friend Bucky, he'd just sit still abiding the new UN law." This is the line that KutuluMike half-correctly called out because the truth it, we don't know. But you don't have proof of that sentence you wrote because Steve was _very much against the treaty_ long before Bucky was involved. Whether it was a "downright rampage" or not, he was still _against_ it and we don't have proof that he would have "abidingly" done nothing.

Comment: @8protons Um, I'm not trying to get anyone "off course", neither am I arguing against your comment. It may very well be that you're not arguing any difference. But *I* am just pointing out that difference, nothing else. Sure he was aginst it, that's entirely clear. I still stand by my statement that he was not  planning to go postal over it. Agree with that or not.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Haha okay, I feel ya. And my comment about "not watching the movie" was more so an attempt of mockery at KutuluMike trying to needlessly slight you with "clearly you didn't actually _watch_ the movie".

Comment: Oh, I didn't even read that anyway. I'm sure everyone here watched the movie.

Comment: @8protons he "refused to sign" twice in the movie. Once when it was proposed by Ross, and some signed and some didn't. That was why he was in hiding in Vienna in the first place -- as soon as that law went into effect he would be effectively a fugitive.

Comment: @Random832 Because ironman screwed up big-time in age of ultron?

Answer (score 15):

As expained in [this excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127549/why-is-civil-war-a-captain-america-movie) by @phantom42 on SF/F, Kevin Feige (the head of Marvel's film studio division) [discussed this point](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/09/30/spider-man-can-serve-a-great-purpose-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe) last year, when talking about the number of characters in the movie. The basic explanation is that, while many of the Avengers are in *Civil War*, only a few characters get a real story-arc, and all of those are related to Steve Rogers development as a character:

> "There were a lot of characters in The Winter Soldier, but it felt like a very singular and relatively simple thriller. Civil War follows in that same way," Feige said. "I think that's something [directors Joe and Anthony Russo] pride themselves on, and our screenwriters Chris Markus and Steve McFeely are excellent at giving each character just enough. **They're not full arcs for everybody; it's just enough that their presence is felt and important, but that the very clear single story that is being told is being served at all times.**"

In addition, the central plot of the movie is not the Avengers fighting against a bad guy to save the world. The movie is about Captain America fighting to prove his friend innocent. The other characters are minor, guest, or even cameo appearances, which serve to tie the movie into the larger Cinematic Universe, but they aren't integral to the plot.

In particular, note that

> in the final act, where the climactic battle and resolution happens, it's down to just Steve Rogers, Bucky Barnes, and Tony Stark.

Comment: I just got stuck in something and forgot submitting the answer, anyways +1